# Rate limit of 25 items in dynamoDB batch request

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

i have an array of products that have over 25 items and the `BatchWriteItemCommand()` has a limit of 25 items it can accept, is there a better way i can break the array into smaller chunks? below is what i have done so far

```
let writeResult;
  const chunk = 24;
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i += chunk) {
    let tempArray;
    tempArray = {
      [process.env.DYNAMODB_PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME]: [
        ...products.slice(i, i + chunk),
      ],
    };
    writeResult = await dynamoDb.send(
      new BatchWriteItemCommand({ RequestItems: tempArray })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting on each batch to complete, you should take advantage of JavaScript async nature and fire them all off together and use `Promise.all()`

This code is not accurate as it's from my phone, but you'll get the jist.

```
let count=0
let items =[]
promises =[]
items.foreach(item=>{
  items.push(item)
  if(count % 25 ===0){
   promises.push(writeBatch(items));
    items=[]
  }
})
await Promise.all(promises)

writeBatch(items){
  return <BatchWriteItem>
}
```

Comment: It is kind of confusing to understand your solution, how did you use this parts:

Comment: `[process.env.DYNAMODB_PRODUCTS_TABLE_NAME]: [
        ...products.slice(i, i + chunk),
  ]`

Comment: `writeResult = await dynamoDb.send(
      new BatchWriteItemCommand({ RequestItems: tempArray })
    );`